# Selecting a row in QTreeView programmatically

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtreeview

I have a QTreeView with QFileSystemModel as model.

The QTreeView has SelectionBehavior set to SelectRows.

In my code I read a dataset to select and then select them via:

```
idx = treeview->model()->index(search); 
selection->select(idx, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

This selects a cell, not the row . .

Have added a stupid workaround, but would rather fix this the correct way.

```
for (int col=0; col< treeview->model()->columnCount(); col++) 
{ 
   idx = treeview->model()->index(search, col); 
   selection->select(idx, QItemSelectionModel::Select); 
}
```

Or is that ^^ the only way to do it?

Comment: what is `selection` ?

Comment: I'm assuming that `selection` is a [QItemSelectionModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html).

Comment: @ssc My guess is that `selection` is `treeview->selectionModel()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also select an entire row using an QItemSelection:

```
selection->select (
    QItemSelection (
        treeview->model ()->index (search, 0),
        treeview->model ()->index (search, treeview->model ()->columnCount () - 1)),
    QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

Also if you also want row selection for user clicks you need to set the selection behavior:

```
treeview->setSelectionBehavior (QAbstractItemView::SelectRows)
```

Comment: Trying your solution.

PS. Already had the SelectRows behavior set (as told on second line of question)

Answer (score 31):

If you want to select a full row, you should use the following:

```
selection->select(idx, QItemSelectionModel::Select | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
```

Note that you may sometimes first want to clear the selection:

```
selection->select(idx, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
```

Comment: You could also use `QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect` instead of `QItemSelectionModel::Select` to clear selection automtically before to select.

Comment: This answer is far superior because of the simplicity of `QItemSelectionModel::Rows`. Editing answer to include the comment's suggestion.