# Is there a combo box "findText" equivalent for QTreeView?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview

I'm using PyQt5 (Python of course) and I was able to easily find the entry programatically in the combo box.  I just passed the string to "findText" method.  But I don't see anything in the QTreeView class documentation on how to select one row based on what I know is a file being displayed there.  I looked at keyboardSearch() but just now realized that's used when you type letters on the keyboard (duh).  I see a setSelection() method that takes a rectangle, but I have no idea how I would know dimensions or coordinates of a rectangle with the selection I want?  Especially since I have sorting enabled so the rows can change order.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Justin

Comment: Don't search the view, [search the model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#match).

Comment: Thanks!  This helped to find this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967660/selecting-a-row-in-qtreeview-programatically which then answered my question.    There was also this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912812/how-do-i-select-a-row-in-a-qtreeview-programatically